# SQL query to fetch employees with null and not null commission values of a particular department

Tags: sql, oracle

The table is emp. The input to the query is comm. If the inputted value is 300 then How to fetch employees who have commission 300 or null and belong to deptno 30 and for all other dept the commission should be 300 only. For all other deptno other than 30 if comm is null then they should not be fetched.

Something like below.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    emp a
    WHERE
    a.comm in(
        CASE a.deptno
            WHEN 30 THEN
                (300, NULL)
            ELSE 300
        END
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `OR` condition as follows:

```
WHERE ( (DEPTNO = 30 AND (COMM IS NULL OR COMM = 300) )
      OR (DEPTNO <> 30 AND COMM = 300) )
      -- OR COMM = 300) -- AS EXPLAINED BELOW
```

Here, You can omit the condition `DEPTNO <> 30` but I personally use this practice for such scenarios to avoid any issues. (Your case is simple but in a complicated case, it is very much important to use the negative condition)